# Do I need a ViewModel to take 1-to-many-data to the view?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

This is probably basic stuff, but I can't find the clear answer anywhere..

Lets say I'm doing an MVC (3) application with Entity Framework (EF4), and I have these three classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooID
    public Bar Bar
    public ICollection<Baz> Bazes
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarID
    public string BarText
}

public class Baz
{
    public int BazID
    public Foo Foo
}
```

What would be the best way of taking all the Foo's with related Bar's Baz's so that I can loop through the Foo's and making use of the related items? Do I need to make a ViewModel, and what should it contain?

What I want to end up with is something like

```
@model = IEnumerable<Foo/FooViewModel>

foreach(var foo in model)
{
  @if(foo.Bar.BarID == 1)
  {
    foreach(var baz in foo)
    {
      @baz.BazID
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about how you would like your views to look like. This is a potentially recursive object hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, Question updated, hope it's clearer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specifically need view models.  You could pass your EF objects directly to your view, and in simple CRUD cases that is fine.  In my experience though it is never that JUST simple CRUD.

I typically need to get data from many places that is not all contained in one object.  For example, I might want to show/hide data depending on a person's role in the system.  Foo probably wouldn't know that.  Another example would be a form with a dropdownlist.  You need to pass that info somewhere.  Again, foo probably doesn't know what the options should be.

I'd create a view model for each class and then use AutoMapper to map the domain model to your view model.

Your view model would look like this:

```
public class FooView{
    public BarView Bar { get; set;}
    public ICollection<BazView> Bazes { get; set;}
}

public class BarView{
    public int BarID { get; set; }
    public BazView Baz { get; set; }
}

public class BazView {
    public int BazID { get; set; }
}
```

Your action method would have something like this in it:

```
var foos = fooRepository.GetFoos();
var model = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Foo>,IEnumerable<FooView>>(myFoos);
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems the modelling of this gets a bit bigger than I was expecting, but it seems valid! The more I look in to MVC the more it seems like MVVMC, does anyone get by with just Models Views and Controllers? Thanks again

Comment: @Niclas Lindqvist you can just use your EF model and that is typically fine for simple CRUD apps.  My experience is that it never ends up JUST CRUD.  I edited my answer and went in to more detail on why I use view models.  HTH

Comment: @Brian, no you're right, it's never just CRUD. I'll read in to automapping and all that a bit more, but thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Brian.. How would the BarView contain multiple Baz'es? From what I can tell your view models say that a BarView has a BazView, but I want multiple Bazes on each Foo (and therefor every Bar), any ideas?

Comment: @Niclas Lindqvist are you only interested in **displaying** Baz'es on this view?  I assumed you weren't since you were passing Foo/Bar to it.  After looking at the question further though, it only appears you are using foo/bar to filter baz'es.  If you aren't actually interested in displaying any foo/bar info I'll update the answer to show you how I'd do it.

Comment: @Brian, well maybe the POCOs and the View were too simplified.. I want to be able to show a list of all FooID's, with their corresponding BarID and **all** Bazes (a list of BazIDs effectively)..